# Java Threading with MYSQL puzzled

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am very puzzled by the behavior of MySQL and java threading. I declare this as synchronized and the results I get are clashing. That means that more than one thread is accessing the same function at the same time. This code segment is in the runnable class.
MachineID is the thread id in the order with which it was invoked in the for loop. (It is jsut a number from 1 to 100).

I don't think the table is required information to

This is the output I get

144 18

144 17

144 11

144 13

144 10

144 9

```
    public synchronized int getRow() throws SQLException{
        String query="SELECT * FROM Searches WHERE checked='0'";
        ResultSet results = this.database.executeQuery(query);
        int id=0;
        if(results.next()){
            id=results.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(id+" "+this.machineID);
             query = "UPDATE Searches  SET checked='1' WHERE ID_num='"+id+"'";
             System.out.println(this.database.executeUpdate(query));
        }

        return id;
    }
    public void run() {



                int id=getRow();

                if (id!=0) {
}
}
```

this is where I invoke my threads

```
for (int i = 0; i < verifier.length; i++) {
        verifier[i]=new Thread(new Verifier(main.database,i+1));
        verifier[i].start();
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you spawn threads. `synchronized` on the method synchronizes on `this`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not quite sure of what you mean by that, this is how I invoke them. I suppose I make wrong use of syncrhonized but I am not sure what is the right use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `getRow()` method belongs to the `Verifier` class, then there is no blocking going on. When you declare `synchronized` on a method, it is equivalent to synchronizing on the instance itself. However, you are spawning a new `Verifier` instance for each `Thread`. Each of those is synchronizing on themselves so none block any of the others.

Consider sharing a `Lock` object with each instance of `Verifier` or synchronizing on a shared object.

```
Object lock = new Object();

for (int i = 0; i < verifier.length; i++) {
    verifier[i]=new Thread(new Verifier(main.database,i+1, lock));
    verifier[i].start();
}

...
public int getRow() throws SQLException{
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no point of having a syncrhonize function in a runnable class?

Comment: @user2789433 You can reuse the instance as much as you want, so yes, there is a point, in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sotirios has hit the nail on the head.  But instead of having a new variable to lock on, I would use just a single `Verifier`, and call it from multiple threads.  So you'll have

```
Verifier oneVerifier = new Verifier(main.database, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < verifier.length; i++) {
        verifier[i]=new Thread(oneVerifier);
        verifier[i].start();
}
```

Note - I don't know what that second argument to the `Verifier` constructor is supposed to be.  Chances are, you don't actually need it, but since you don't actually show the constructor, I thought I'd leave it in.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it didn't work. You can see the edit.

Comment: I don't actually understand your edit; but honestly, if you can't get my answer to work, use Sotirios' one.  He knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

No synchronization is happening at all it's is similar to

```
synchronize(this)
```

And the same instance is not shared across the threads so there is no synchronization happening at all. 
So you need to share a lock object across the `Runnable` instances i.e. `Verifier` in constructer like:

```
public class Verifier implements Runnable{
    private final Object lock;
    public Verifier(Object lock){
         this.lock=lock;
    }
```

Than you can synchronize on the lock like:

```
synchronize(lock)
```

else you can synchronize on the class object as well:

```
synchronize(Verifier.class)
```