# Absurd Java MultiThreading and MySQL syncrhonization

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

Related to the question: 
[Java Threading with MYSQL puzzled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992710/java-threading-with-mysql-puzzled)

The counter int, is synchronized, the function calls to executeQuery are not synchronized.
Results I am getting

counter: 1

row from MYSQL: 1

counter: 2

row from MYSQL: 1

counter: 3

row from MYSQL: 1

Expected Output-> row from MYSQL: should be the same as counter

All the threads run at the same time the first query. Hence they get the same id of the result. However they synchronize for the counter iteration. To me this is absurd. Is this behavior documented? How can I bypass it?
Verifier.java

```
public void run() {

int id = 0;
    String query = "SELECT ID_num FROM Searches WHERE checked='0'";
    ResultSet results;
    synchronized (this.database) {
        results = this.database.executeQuery(query);
        if (results.next()) {
            id = results.getInt(1);
            query = "UPDATE Searches  SET checked='1' WHERE ID_num='"
                    + id + "'";
            this.database.counter++;
            System.out.println(this.database.counter);
            System.out.println(id);

        }
    }
}
```

Core.java

```
for (int i = 0; i < verifier.length; i++) {
            MySQL database=new MySQL();
           verifier[i]=new Thread(new Verifier(database,i+1));  
            verifier[i].start(); 
    }
```

MySQL.java

```
public class MySQL{
    int counter=0;
....

}
```

Comment: Your code as it is means your update query, increment and sysout are synchronized on 3 different object locks not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I see the issue, you update query is not committing the results. You shld commit after update and  you will see that table count will also change.

EDIT2: OP says

> Expected Output-> row from MYSQL: should be the same as counter

but with current code this can't be achieved. Following is the logic of program:

1. Fetch all rows with `checked='0'` .
2. Thread will update all the rows fetched with `checked='1'`
3. Second thread comes and it tries to find rows with `checked='0'` which will always be 0 if first thread commits the rows.

In order to achieve this behaviour you should not hard code `checked='0'` in your query instead that should be derived from thread count [the `i` value passed to Verifier]

EDIT3: 
There is a correction here, threads will not execute sequentially as new `database` is created for each thread. Above points will still hold true but this will make achiving expected result more difficult.

Comment: The counter is just to show sync is actually working. My main problem is that all threads fetch the same row instead of sequential rows.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by, "You shld commit after update and you will see that table count will also change."

Comment: Just executing a query will not commit the results if auto commit is set to false. So either set auto commit to true to you should commit explicitly.